# How to tell python to read/process the selected column

Tags: python, csv

I want python to read/process the selected column (where I have highlighted).

[image]

Here is the sample script in python

```
import csv

def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    return lines

def write_csv(filename, data):
    headers = ["date"] + [f"R{i}" for i in range(1, 501)]
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)

def format_data(lines):
    data = {}
    current_replicate = None
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()  # remove leading/trailing whitespace
        if not line or line.startswith("#"):  # skip empty lines and lines starting with #
            continue
        elif "Replicate #" in line:
            current_replicate = "R" + line.split("#")[1].strip()
        else:
            parts = line.split()
            if len(parts) == 4:  # ensure there are 4 parts
                year, month, day, value = parts
                date = f"{year}/{month.zfill(2)}/{day.zfill(2)}"
                if date not in data:
                    data[date] = {f"R{i}": '' for i in range(1, 501)}
                data[date][current_replicate] = value
            else:
                print(f"Unexpected line format: {line}")
    return data


def main():
    lines = read_file('REP_4.5_500.txt') #
    formatted_data = format_data(lines)
    write_csv('Test1.csv', list(formatted_data.values()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Appreciate your though and suggestion on this script.

Many Thanks

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: The lines you want have 6 parts, not 4 parts.

Comment: I tried with 6 parts, but it does not work

Comment: @PeterSerey: "does not work" is not really helpful without much more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines you want have 6 parts. So change

```
            if len(parts) == 4:  # ensure there are 4 parts
                year, month, day, value = parts
```

to

```
            if len(parts) == 6:  # ensure there are 4 parts
                year, month, day, value, _1, _2 = parts
```

Also `write_csv()` is just looping through the keys of `data`, not its values. You need to get the values, then add a `date` element to it.

```
def write_csv(filename, data):
    headers = ["date"] + [f"R{i}" for i in range(1, 501)]
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writeheader()
        for date, row in data.items():
            row['date'] = date
            writer.writerow(row)
```

And you should just pass `formatted_data` to the function, not convert it to a list.

```
def main():
    lines = read_file('REP_4.5_500.txt') #
    formatted_data = format_data(lines)
    write_csv('Test1.csv', formatted_data)
```

Comment: it resulted an error: as 

  File csv.py:157 in writerows

  File csv.py:147 in _dict_to_list

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: I've added the fix for that.

Comment: It still has as error, as:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Don't use `formatted_data.values()`, just pass `formatted_data`

Comment: I still have an error

write_csv('Test1.csv', list(formatted_data()))

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: It's not a function, get rid of `()`

Comment: And not `list()`.

Comment: Thanks you so much. It works now

Could i please ask a final question on "year, month, day, value, _1, _2 = parts"? what does it mean?

Comment: `_1` and `_2` are simply unused variables to hold the last two parts that you're not interested in. Other than that it means the same thing as your original code.

Comment: What if i am interested in the column that is close to the one i have highlighted (start with 6.752)? How do I change that?

Comment: Just use more variables. Or access them by index `parts[4]`. This is all very basic Python list access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code - you need pandas to be installed. The process is:

- reading the whole content of the file
- filter and only selected the tabular part
- refine and make sure all are just separated by same separator (here, making sure it is not both tab `\t` and space)
- make a data frame and select the column and finally save to CSV -- here you can specify how you want to save it, with index or without and with header, etc - read more here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# read the whole content of the file:
with open('REP_4.5_500.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    content = fp.read()

# trim the content
filtered_content = content.split("Replicate # 1",1)[1].replace("\t", " ").replace("  ", " ").strip()

# create dataframe and filter to the selected column
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(filtered_content), sep=" ", header=None)[3]

#  write as csv
df.to_csv("Test1.csv")
```

Btw, better to put the raw text file or a sample of next time - this will helps a lot to replicate your work and help you fix it :)

- Edited:
  Based on the discussion in the comments:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# read the whole content of the file:
with open('REP_4.5_500.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    content = fp.read()

# trim the content
filtered_content = content.split("Replicate # 1",1)[1].replace("\t", " ").replace("  ", " ").strip()

# create dataframe and filter to the selected column
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(filtered_content), sep=" ", header=None)[3]

# keep Replicate # 1 as header for this column
df=pd.DataFrame(df).rename(columns={3:"Replicate # 1"})

#  write as text file
df.to_csv("Test1.txt", index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: Hi Ehsan, 
It is possible to write as txt file? because i have a very big file, and I can;t load into excel. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is the same process: try this df.to_csv("Test1.txt", index=False, header=False) - you can also open the current csv with your text editors :)

Comment: sorry i forgot to ask
Is it possible to keep this row: Replicate # 1 (please see my attached image) as I may need to reframe my data later

Comment: yeah sure, just keep it as header and then set header to true: 

add this line before save the file:
df=pd.DataFrame(df).rename(columns={3:"Replicate # 1"})

and change the pd.to_csv as:
df.to_csv("Test1.txt", index=False, header=True)